# /usr/bin/cmake: is a directory. Not able to grab the version of cmake?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake

I just have installed CMAKE in my ubuntu machine.. So when I do whereis cmake, it gives me the actual path

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~/CMAKE/cmake-2.8.11$ whereis cmake
cmake: /usr/bin/cmake
```

But whenever I try to get the version of cmake, I always get the below message.. I am not sure what wrong I am doing here?

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~/CMAKE/cmake-2.8.11$ /usr/bin/cmake --version
-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: is a directory
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command `type` instead of `whereis` for locating executables.

```
$ type -a cmake
cmake is /usr/bin/cmake

$ /usr/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.4
```

The command `whereis` doesn't use your current environment, it looks in several locations that are typically used for executables, such as:

*excerpt from whereis man page*

```
FILES
       /{bin,sbin,etc}

       /usr/{lib,bin,old,new,local,games,include,etc,src,man,sbin,
                           X386,TeX,g++-include}

       /usr/local/{X386,TeX,X11,include,lib,man,etc,bin,games,emacs}
```

Comment: While this is good, he specified the full path to the binary in his example, which could not be a function or alias.

Comment: @jordanm - I want to see the output of `type` before we go any further with this. Something strange is up! I can think of several reasons that `whereis` would report as it did and mislead one to think the executable is `/usr/bin/cmake` when there is an actual directory there.